# Gradle sync failed..missing google

Tags: android, android-studio

Im not so god in android studio, but im trying to make it work.
But when im stuck i dont now what to do.
So now i hope someone can help me.

I have 5 errors.

Error:Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:11.8.0

Error:Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.8.0

Error:Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base:11.8.0

Error:Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.8.0

Error:Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0

I cant install repository and sync project.

this is my gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 9
        versionName "1.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url uri('mint-plugin-repo-5.1.0')
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //For error logcat
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.16'
    compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.12.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.+'
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.+'
    compile 'com.splunk:mint-android-sdk:5.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.daasuu:CountAnimationTextView:0.1.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `google()` and add this before `jcenter()` like this in your gradle and one more important thing you have to use `implementation` instead of `compile` :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()    // add this
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
             url 'https://maven.google.com/'
             name 'Google'
           }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()   // add this
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
            maven {
              url 'https://maven.google.com/'
              name 'Google'
          }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 9
        versionName "1.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url uri('mint-plugin-repo-5.1.0')
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //For error logcat
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.16'
    implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.12.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.+'
    implementation 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.+'
    implementation 'com.splunk:mint-android-sdk:5.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.daasuu:CountAnimationTextView:0.1.1'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.+'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: try this, and all i get is error:
Gradle DSL method not found: 'google()'

Comment: What do you want to say?

Comment: It doesn't work.....

Comment: repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

remove this  because it is taking fully maven

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `google()` to your Project level build.gradle file. Add it before `jcenter()`.
Also, note that `compile` is deprecated and you should use `implementation` instead.

#### EDIT

If the above does not work, you may need to disable gradle offline work option on "File >> Settings >> Build, Execution, Deployment >> Gradle >> Offline work".

Comment: no it doesent work.....

Comment: @Niklas See my edit

Comment: now i get this:
Error:Could not find play-services-auth.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0)

Comment: Update your gradle version to `3.2.1`, `play-services` to `4.0.1` then go to your `gradle-wrapper.properties` files and update the value to `gradle-4.6-all.zip`

Comment: everything i try i get error. i try to update, change to new version.
And i now this app is working.

Comment: this is only error i get now...
`Could not find google-services.json while looking in [src/nullnull/debug, src/debug/nullnull, src/nullnull, src/debug, src/nullnullDebug]` and 

`registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)` amd the last one

`Parsing json file: /home/niklas/Desktop/app/google-services.json`